# Writing a cross platform background service

Tags: python, node.js, cross-platform

Can I write a service in Python or Node.js and be able to run it as a service on different platforms without installing python or node.js on that machine?

Let us say I have a installer that installs my application, while installing the application it will also tell that it will install a service. This service will auto start on system boot. It should work on windows,osx, and linux. The service will just watch a directory for file changes and make appropriate actions with it.

I have seen easy to implement packages for python and node.js that can do this watching and are also already cross platform but both needs the user to install and setup the python or node.js package first. (or is there a way to not need to install python/node.js?)

So what are the possible solutions to:

- User is not technical so should not install node.js/python distributions
- Have a service that gets installed with the client on windows/osx/linux
- Have the service bootup on start up

Or should I write a service in C++ and build each for each platforms? If that’s the case is there any package that I can use for such task? (I have to do appropriate task for each thing that happens so I can't use prebuilt services)

This problem is more of a windows and osx problem than linux.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I have the same requirement but in java.